# Tensorflow Lite Model Maker KeyError: "Pose"

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, pose-estimation

I'm trying to train a model using the [Tensorflow lite model maker](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/tutorials/model_maker_object_detection) but i can't load the data. I'm using the `object_detector.DataLoader.from_pascal_voc` method and I get an error`Key Error: pose`. Please help me!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `object_detector.DataLoader.from_pascal_voc` method to load the data, then your XML data must follow the Pascal VOC format. For example,

```
<annotation>
  <folder>Folder 1 Name</folder>
  ...
  <object>
    <name>Object 1 Name</object>
    <pose>Unspecified</pose>
    ...
  </object>
</annotation>
```

If you are not using `pose` information, then you can annotate your data with `Unspecified`.